# Play video using ffmpeg subprocess

Tags: python, ffmpeg, subprocess

The following code stuck in the middle of the video. I want to play the video start at `start_seconds` and end at `end_seconds`.

```
import subprocess
import cv2
import numpy as np
import subprocess

def play_video_with_ffmpeg(video_path, start_seconds, end_seconds):
print(start_seconds)

    # Set the desired frame size
    width = 920
    height = 600
    
    # Set the window position
    print("here")
    window_x = 600  # X position
    window_y = 10  # Y position
    cv2.namedWindow('Video Player', cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
    cv2.moveWindow('Video Player', window_x, window_y)
    
    # Build the ffmpeg command to skip to the desired start time and end time
    command = [
        'ffmpeg',
        '-ss', str(start_seconds),
        '-i', video_path,
        '-t', str((end_seconds - start_seconds)),
        '-vf', f'scale={width}:{height}',
        '-r', '30',
        '-f', 'image2pipe',
        '-pix_fmt', 'bgr24',
        '-vcodec', 'rawvideo',
        '-'
    ]
    
    # Open a subprocess to execute the ffmpeg command
    process = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    
    # Create a buffer to hold the frame data
    buffer_size = width * height * 3
    frame_buffer = bytearray(buffer_size)
    
    while process.poll() is None:
        # Read the frame from the subprocess stdout into the buffer
        bytes_read = process.stdout.readinto(frame_buffer)
    
        if bytes_read == buffer_size:
            # Convert the frame buffer to a numpy array
            frame = np.frombuffer(frame_buffer, dtype='uint8').reshape((height, width, 3))
    
            # Resize the frame
            frame_resized = cv2.resize(frame, (width, height), interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
    
            # Display the frame
            cv2.imshow('Video Player', frame_resized)
    
            if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
                break
    
    process.stdout.close()
    process.stderr.close()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I expect to play the video start from `start_second` and end at `end_second`. I used `cv2.set` but it took long time to play from start_second.

Comment: Can you please respond my answer? I would like to know if my answer solves your issue or not.

Answer (score 0):

The main issue is setting `stderr=subprocess.PIPE` without "draining" the `stderr` pipe.
When `stderr` buffer is full, FFmpeg sub-process halts and wait for `stderr` data to be read.

We may use a thread that reads `stderr` in the background.
A simpler solution is removing `stderr=subprocess.PIPE`, and adding `'-hide_banner', '-loglevel', 'error'` flags to FFmpeg (stderr is going to be written only in case of an error).

For debugging we may add `-report` flag (we may need it since we don't have the content that is written to `stderr`).

---

For testing we may build a synthetic pattern using FFmpeg CLI:

`ffmpeg -y -f lavfi -i testsrc=size=192x108:rate=10:duration=300 test.mp4`

---

Code sample (playing from second 100 to 200):

```
import subprocess
import cv2
import numpy as np
import subprocess

def play_video_with_ffmpeg(video_path, start_seconds, end_seconds):
    print(start_seconds)

    # Set the desired frame size
    width = 920
    height = 600
    
    # Set the window position
    print("here")
    window_x = 600  # X position
    window_y = 10  # Y position
    cv2.namedWindow('Video Player', cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
    cv2.moveWindow('Video Player', window_x, window_y)
    
    # Build the ffmpeg command to skip to the desired start time and end time
    command = [
        'ffmpeg',
        '-hide_banner', '-loglevel', 'error',  # Instead of stderr=subprocess.PIPE, use -hide_banner and -loglevel error for hiding stderr (we may add -report flag for debugging).
        '-ss', str(start_seconds),        
        '-i', video_path,        
        '-t', str((end_seconds - start_seconds)),
        '-vf', f'scale={width}:{height}',
        '-r', '30', # Consider not using '-r', '30', keep the original framerate of the input
        '-f', 'rawvideo', #'image2pipe', # -f image2pipe is working but -f rawvideo is more elegant (the output format is "raw video")
        '-pix_fmt', 'bgr24',
        '-vcodec', 'rawvideo',
        '-'
    ]
    
    # Open a subprocess to execute the ffmpeg command
    process = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    
    # Create a buffer to hold the frame data
    buffer_size = width * height * 3
    frame_buffer = bytearray(buffer_size)
    
    while process.poll() is None:
        # Read the frame from the subprocess stdout into the buffer
        bytes_read = process.stdout.readinto(frame_buffer)
    
        if bytes_read == buffer_size:
            # Convert the frame buffer to a numpy array
            frame = np.frombuffer(frame_buffer, dtype='uint8').reshape((height, width, 3))
    
            # Resize the frame
            #frame_resized = cv2.resize(frame, (width, height), interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)  # No need to resize - there is a scale filter: '-vf', f'scale={width}:{height}'
    
            # Display the frame
            cv2.imshow('Video Player', frame) #frame_resized)
    
            if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
                break
        else:
            break  # Break the loop if bytes_read != buffer_size (in case of an error).
    
    process.stdout.close()
    #process.stderr.close()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()


play_video_with_ffmpeg('test.mp4', 100, 200)
```